# Iniciarlizar y parar quagga.js

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando el código quagga.js y me  gustaría poder inicializarlo cuando yo quisiera. Se como pararlo pero después no se como hacer que vuelva a funcionar sin refrescar la pagina.
Os pongo el enlace a la web de la librería.
https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/live_w_locator.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //Inicializo       
     Quagga.init({
        inputStream : {
          name : "Live",
          type : "LiveStream",
        },

        locate: "True",
        decoder : {
          readers : ["code_128_reader","code_39_reader"]
        }
      }, function(err) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return
          }

            multiple: false;
            halfSample: true;
            patchSize: "small"; // x-small, small, medium, large, x-large
            console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
            Quagga.start();
      });

      //Al detectar el código, oculto el div de la camara y hago un stop
      Quagga.onDetected(function (data) { //Al detectar el codigo
              var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
                track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{torch: false}]});
                $("#barCode").val(data.codeResult.code); //Asigno el código resultando a un campo input
                   $("#interactive").hide(); //Oculto el div de la camara
                  beep();
                  Quagga.stop(data); //Paro Quagga
        });

    }); //Fin de document ready
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado con [`Quagga.start();`](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/#api)? Si necesitas continuar escaneando ¿por que lo detienes?

Comment: Buenas, si he intentando eso y recibo este error: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined. Necesito  que solo detecte un código y al detectarlo lo paro y lo escondo pero se puede dar el caso de que el codigo no lo haya detectado bien o que por alguna razón el usuario necesite volver a hacer un escaneo.

Comment: Lo he solucionado metiendo el codigo de inicialización en una función y llamando a esa función. Solo con el start no funciona, antes debes inicializar. Quagga.init({ .... Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

agrega tu código en una función y luego manda a llamar la misma desde un input button

```
public fucntion start(){$(document).ready(function(){
     //Inicializo       
         Quagga.init({
            inputStream : {
              name : "Live",
              type : "LiveStream",
            },
    
            locate: "True",
            decoder : {
              readers : ["code_128_reader","code_39_reader"]
            }
          }, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return
              }
    
                multiple: false;
                halfSample: true;
                patchSize: "small"; // x-small, small, medium, large, x-large
                console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
                Quagga.start();
          });
    
          //Al detectar el código, oculto el div de la camara y hago un stop
          Quagga.onDetected(function (data) { //Al detectar el codigo
                  var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
                    track.applyConstraints({advanced: [{torch: false}]});
                    $("#barCode").val(data.codeResult.code); //Asigno el código resultando a un campo input
                       $("#interactive").hide(); //Oculto el div de la camara
                      beep();
                      Quagga.stop(data); //Paro Quagga
            });
    
        });}
```

en tu html :

```
<input type="button" onclick="start()" name="iniciar" />
```